# adding a column into my output

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, calculated-columns

I would like to add my own column in addition to two existing ones(Tickets and Request Date) into my output when I run my query.

The code:

```
select f02_ticket_number as 'Tickets', f02_requested_date as 'Request 
date'
from client_uli_zendesk_ticket 
left outer join co_customer on f02_cst_key=cst_key
left outer join co_individual_ext on cst_key=ind_cst_key_ext
left join co_individual on ind_cst_key_ext=ind_cst_key
where f02_status<>'deleted'
```

The output:

```
Tickets    Request Date
1          5/8/2017
2          4/19/2017
```

This is what I would like it to look like:

```
Tickets   Request Date   My added column
1         5/8/2017         May/2017
2         4/19/2017        April/2017
3         6/19/2017        June/2017
4         7/19/2018        July/2018
5         8/19/2018        August/2018
```

I understand that I would write a case statement to categorize request Date into my new column,however, I don't know how to add my new column through the select statement including the proper data type.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
select f02_ticket_number as Tickets, f02_requested_date as [Request 
date],
       datename(month, f02_requested_date) + '/' + datename(year, f02_requested_date)
from . . .;
```

This assumes that your internationalization settings are set to English.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
select f02_ticket_number as 'Tickets', f02_requested_date as 'Request date', CONVERT(CHAR(4), f02_requested_date, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), f02_requested_date, 120) AS 'Your Added Column name'
from client_uli_zendesk_ticket 
left outer join co_customer on f02_cst_key=cst_key
left outer join co_individual_ext on cst_key=ind_cst_key_ext
left join co_individual on ind_cst_key_ext=ind_cst_key
where f02_status<>'deleted'
```